# How can resize the image with user defined names with user defined folder in typo3

Tags: typo3

I have a typo3 site.
Where i need to resize the  images with user defined names and then store it in a folder

Any idea how can we do this ?

Comment: can you explain what "user defined names" means? Who is the user? How do you get the images? There are plenty of possibilities which to choose depends on your needs.

Comment: Generally the resized images will store in typo3temp with some name
But i wanted have a name which is defined by me for resized images

For example if the image1.png instead of 2343566.gif

Comment: What do you actually want? I guess renaming images is just the way, but what is the target? If this is for SEO, try http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/fl_realurl_image

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this TypoScript option helps:

```
config.meaningfulTempFilePrefix = 1
```

Now when resizing an image and by this storing the resulting file in typo3temp the filename won't be gibberish only but still containing the original filename.

http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/CONFIG